# How to show different static cells for different iOS versions?(Static `UITableView`)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating a Setting Screen with the help of **static `UITableVIew`**.

Now, there are certain cells(Functions) that doesn't work in some *iOS version* ,so I want to hide them from my tableView in a way that doesn't affect other cell.

E.G. -  in the below Image , `Change App Icon` function **won't work in iOS version less than 10.3** so I want to hide it for devices only which have lower iOS version than 10.3 (It should be displayed for iOS 10.3+)

[image]

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Please elaborate "I want to hide them from my tableView in a way that doesn't affect other cells."

Comment: I mean if I remove a cell from a section then section should shrink too.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the heightForRowAtIndexPath method and inside it, check the iOS version and return the height of cells based on it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return 40
    } else {
        return ( (indexPath.row == 3) ? 0 : 50)
    }
}
```

As its a static table view, you already know the row and section. So in the above code, we are hiding the third row if the iOS version is below 13.0 by making its height 0. For other rows, it will make height as 50

Comment: It works perfectly , Thanks !!!! ,please upvote my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the available attribute for the same while in cellForRowAtIndexPath function. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` try the following:

```
if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
    //load all cells here
  } else {
    // load just the ones you want excluding those which won't work with iOS version less than 10.3
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain further ??

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear enough.
How do you implement your cells? If you use a storyboard – you should hide particular cells.
If you use the code, you should check the iOS version at each time of table handling: from cell registering until each delegate method in order to provide the corresponding information.